# how to prove the associative law of the compositon operation (.) in Haskell

Tags: haskell

say ,

```
    f :: a -> b 
    g :: b -> c 
    h :: c -> d
```

why the equation

```
    h.(g.f) = (h.g).f
```

is right?
how to prove it?
and the composition operation is just a basic operation in Haskell,
or we can get one by ourselves? if so how to achieve it?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/523906/show-that-function-compositions-are-associative

Comment: With `comp f g x = f (g x)`, ``f `comp` g`` is same as `f.g`.

Comment: You can click the "[Source](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#.)" link next to [the documentation for `(.)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:.) to see how it's implemented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define the composition operator yourself as follows:

```hs
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
g . f = \x -> g (f x)
```

Now, to prove associativity:

```hs
lhs = h . (g . f)
    = \x -> h ((g . f) x)         -- substitution
    = \x -> h ((\y -> g (f y)) x) -- substitution
    = \x -> h (g (f x))           -- beta reduction

rhs = (h . g) . f
    = \x -> (h . g) (f x)         -- substitution
    = \x -> (\y -> h (g y)) (f x) -- substitution
    = \x -> h (g (f x))           -- beta reduction
```

Now, we have `lhs = rhs`. QED.